# Google upload fails for some files

Tags: python, file, upload

Tried the file upload to google using the following lines of code and uploaded the apk files and got error for some files and for the rest it is working fine.

```
def upload_file_drive(folder_id, access_token, path, name):
    para = {"name": name, "parents": [folder_id]}
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    files = {'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json'), 'file': open(path, "rb")}
    response = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart", headers=headers, files=files)
    return response
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `some files`. So can you explain about `some files`? For example, those are the mimeType, the file size and the error message. By the way, in your script, `uploadType=multipart` is used. In this case, when the file size is more than 5 MB, an error occurs. Please be careful this. If your issue is this, please upload it using the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Comment: I tried with .apk files with size larger than 5MB and I got the error like "Malformed multipart body"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, the size might be the reason of your issue. So how about trying to use the resumable upload?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try resumable upload.